# Resampling time series data using python/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, time-series

I am trying to resample some time series data using the following code in python. What I am trying to do is take 2 arrays, one which has observation times and the other that has values. in the given example `time` and `values`. I want to record observations at particular time intervals, say every `0.1` in the time interval `[0,2]`. that would give an array of `[[time, values]]` that looks like `[[0.0, 1], [1.0, 3], [1.2, 5], [1.3, 6], [2.0, 8]]`. now at every intermediate value between the next update I want to fill it with last value, for eg. between `[0.0, 1], [1.0, 3]` i want pairs  `[0.1, 1] ..[0.9, 1]`.

```
import numpy as np

time =   np.array([0, 0.0120, 0.0130, 1, 1.02, 1.2,  1.3, 1.32, 2 ])
values = np.array([1,   3,    2,      3,  4,     5,    6,   7,  8])

#time_interval = 1e-1

newvals = []

def resample(time, values, time_interval):
    currentTime = 0.0
    newvals = []
    vals = []
    for idx in range(len(time)):
        t = time[idx]
        data = values[idx]
        if t >= currentTime:
            newvals.append([max(t, currentTime),data])
            currentTime = max(t, currentTime) +time_interval
        else:
             continue 

    #vals = []
    newvals_copy = np.array(newvals)
    seen = set(newvals_copy[:,0])
    for idx in range(len(newvals)):
        rec_time = newvals[idx][0]
        #seen.add(rec_time)
        #print(idx, idx+1, len(newvals))
        next_idx = idx+1
        if next_idx == len(newvals):
            break
        else:
            #print(idx)
            next_time = newvals[idx+1][0]
            intermediate_val = np.arange(rec_time , next_time, time_interval)
            #print(intermediate_val[])
            for value in intermediate_val:
                if value not in seen:
                    #print(idx, value)
                    newvals.append([value, newvals[idx][1]])
                    
    newvals = np.array(newvals)
    newvals=np.unique(newvals, axis=0)
    return newvals#, len(newvals)
print(resample(time, values, 1e-1))
#print(np.arange(0,2.1,0.1), len(np.arange(0,2.1,0.1)))
```

this test case produces the desired output,

```
[[0.  1. ]
 [0.1 1. ]
 [0.2 1. ]
 [0.3 1. ]
 [0.4 1. ]
 [0.5 1. ]
 [0.6 1. ]
 [0.7 1. ]
 [0.8 1. ]
 [0.9 1. ]
 [1.  3. ]
 [1.1 3. ]
 [1.2 5. ]
 [1.3 6. ]
 [1.4 6. ]
 [1.5 6. ]
 [1.6 6. ]
 [1.7 6. ]
 [1.8 6. ]
 [1.9 6. ]
 [2.  8. ]]
```

however, running on `real_data = resample(real_time, real_values, 1e-1)` where
`real_time` = https://filedropper.com/d/s/7Q5IqtRzEh42p2oU0qTrbnuTb8iRK4 ,

`real_values` = https://filedropper.com/d/s/hixCEY7QmqGcDBjEanhX2UgocKmV4K

```
real_data[:,0] = [0.         0.1        0.10000947 0.20000947 0.20000981 0.30000981
 0.30001438 0.40001438 0.40002427 0.50002427 0.50006157 0.60006157
 0.6000784  0.7000784  0.70009857 0.80009857 0.80010533 0.90010533
 0.90012181 1.00012181 1.00020397 1.10020397 1.1002512  1.2002512
 1.20025706 1.30025706 1.30026507 1.40026507 1.4002744  1.5002744
 1.50028026 1.60028026 1.60029566 1.70029566 1.70029855 1.80029855
 1.80030084 1.90030084 1.90032208]
```

which is incorrect. The expected output should be the same as the test case,

```
  real_data[:,0]=[0.  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7
     1.8 1.9 2. ]
```

I am guessing the error is due to how floating points/decimals are handled? but I am not sure how to remedy this.
**EDIT**
Tried rounding based on comments, better but not ideal
`real_data = resample(np.round(real_time, decimals = 1), real_values, 1e-1)`still gives an array with duplicates `real_data[:,0][0.  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2. ]`

Ideally I want to make this solution workable for arbitrary data sets and time interval values.

Comment: Have you tried `real_data = np.round(real_data, decimals = 1)`?

Comment: that's a good idea honestly did not try it till you brought it up. `real_data = resample(np.round(real_time, decimals = 1), real_values, 1e-1)`still gives an array with duplicates `real_data[:,0][0.  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6
 1.7 1.8 1.9 2. ]`

Comment: I can't quite follow what you need. It seems like you should be able to use [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html), have you tried it? As a rule, you almost never need loops in NumPy-land, so I'm sure there's a simpler way to achieve what you need.

Comment: To clarify what I don't understand: why is the expected value at time=0.1 given as 1 and not 2, since 2 was recorded at a later time? What is the rule for discarding those samples at 0.0120 and 0.0130?

Comment: I essentially only want to keep values that occur at [0., val], [0.1 val]...etc. anything that is recorded at something finer resolution i want to throw away. interp1d is what i might need thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly something like this does what you need:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

# The test data.
time = np.array([0, 0.0120, 0.0130, 1, 1.02, 1.2, 1.3, 1.32, 2])
values = np.array([1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

# The new time basis we're aiming for.
t_new = np.linspace(0, 2, 21)

# Throw away times that we don't like.
new_data = [[t, v] for t, v in zip(time, values) if t in t_new]
t_clean, v_clean = np.array(new_data).T

# Make the interpolator function.
func = interp1d(t_clean, v_clean, kind="previous")

# Interpolate the data into the new time basis.
v_new = func(t_new)
```

Now `v_new` is like:

```
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 3., 3., 3., 6., 6., 6., 6.,
       6., 6., 6., 8.])
```